# Optmizing ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, performance, order-by, query-performance

I'm new to MySQL and have written the following query (see below).

**PROBLEM:**
The query returns accurate data but takes about 40 seconds to execute. 
However, When I remove the `ORDER BY` part, it takes 0.06sec.

I have indexes on each of the `ORDER BY` columns and am unsure what else to do.
If anybody can rewrite/recommend changes it'd be greatly informative.

**CODE:**

```
 SELECT DISTINCT username
    FROM `users`
    WHERE `in_progress` = 0
      AND scraped_from IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT `username`
         FROM source_accounts
         WHERE group_users = 'New Users'
           AND (`type` = 'users' OR `type` = 'both')
           AND `use` = '1')
      AND username NOT IN
        (SELECT user_tofollow
         FROM `follow_history`
         WHERE owner_account = 'admin')
    ORDER BY real_user DESC,
             IF((last_used) IS NULL,'0','1'),
             IF((last_update)>3,'1','0'),
             DATE(last_used),
             IF((user_ratio)>100,'1','0') LIMIT 1000;
```

**EXPLAIN:**

```
1   PRIMARY     scraped_users   ref     idx1,scraped_from,in_progress,username  in_progress     1   const   687025  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY     <subquery2>     eq_ref  <auto_key>  <auto_key>  767     userstack.users.scraped_from    1   Distinct
2   MATERIALIZED    source_accounts     ref     username,group_users,type,use   group_users     767     const   48  Using index condition; Using where; Distinct
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  follow_history  index_subquery  user_tofollow   user_tofollow   767     func    1   Using where
```

Comment: I smiled at the *"works well, but takes about 40 seconds to execute"* but I guess you meant it returns correct results. Please add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` output for the 3 tables and the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` output of your query.

Comment: From "I have indexes on each of the `ORDER BY`" I can say that you should learn about composite (multicolumn) indexes. And the subqueries in `IN` are unfortunatelly not well optimized in most mysql versions. As ypercube says, [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) to get the query plan.

Comment: Looking into composite indexes. Explain added above ^

Comment: Can you add the explain for the "fast version" too, to compare it?

Comment: Actually the `EXPLAIN` is the exact same if I include the `ORDER BY` or not, which is what is detracting from the speed

Comment: Then only thing that helps the "unordered" one is the LIMIT optimization (the other EXPLAIN should not show `Using filesort` in the first row probably).

Comment: Is the first `DISTINCT` really needed? Do you have several `users` with the same `username`?

Comment: From the explain it seems the subqueries themselves are actually optimized quite well, the materialized one is good and the dependent one probably uses "not exists" optimization (`explain extended ... ; show warning;` could tell you for sure). The problem is that the only remaining condition is `in_progress = 0` and that is not selective enough. You should rewrite it so at least the first subquery is a join instead. Your order by is unfortunatelly not optimizable to a index scan as it contains some functions/expressions and not "pure" columns.

Answer (score 0):

The performance problem is not with `ORDER BY`, itself...

`NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` optimizes poorly.  This works much better (if it is practical in your cases):
`JOIN ... ON ... WHERE id IS NULL`

If that can't be done, then this may be better:
`NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM ... )`

Answer (score -4):

Make sure you have indexes on the columns you are attempting to order by.  Here is a pretty good reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: It is actually not possible to optimize the `ORDER BY` clause as it contains some functions.